# transfer udp packets in android

Tags: android, udp

These codes are for sending and receiving udp packets in android. When I run it in emulator, It can receive data. But it isn't work in real devices. what is problem?

In Eclipse:

```
public class UdpServer extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private TextView textView; 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    runUdpServer();
}
private static final int UDP_SERVER_PORT = 11111;
private static final int MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN = 1500;
private void runUdpServer() {
    String lText;
    byte[] lMsg = new byte[MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN];
    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(lMsg, lMsg.length);
    DatagramSocket ds = null;
    try {
        ds = new DatagramSocket(UDP_SERVER_PORT);
        //disable timeout for testing
        //ds.setSoTimeout(100000);
        ds.receive(dp);
        lText = new String(lMsg, 0, dp.getLength());
        Log.i("UDP packet received", lText);
        textView.setText(lText);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (ds != null) {
            ds.close();
        }
    }

}
}
```

UdpClient.java:

```
public class UdpClient extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    runUdpClient();
    finish();
}
private static final int UDP_SERVER_PORT = 11111;
private void runUdpClient()  {
    String udpMsg = "hello world from UDP client " + UDP_SERVER_PORT;
    DatagramSocket ds = null;
    try {
        ds = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
        DatagramPacket dp;
        dp = new DatagramPacket(udpMsg.getBytes(), udpMsg.length(), serverAddr, UDP_SERVER_PORT);
        ds.send(dp);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (ds != null) {
            ds.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

This is code link.
[Link](http://www.roman10.net/android-udp-client-and-server-communication-programmingillustrated-with-example/)
Does it need a modem? Does it need connecting to the internet? Does it need Wi-Fi on?

Comment: emulator posibly may not forward UPD packets across the system

Comment: It work in Emulator! But on android devices it is not work! Is that code correct? or need other things to do, like a router, modem, connecting the internet, wi-fi,...?

Comment: Sure it need your phones to be in one wi-fi network.